# Does libVLC/MobileVLCKit support 4k, 8K, 12K videos in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, vlc, libvlc

Does libVLC support 4k, 8K , 12K videos in iOS. 
I am playing 4K videos from the bundle in iOS app using libVLC and it doesn't play properly. Although the Full HD and HD videos are playing okay.

This is the GitHub code I am using currently.
https://github.com/maknapp/vlckitSwiftSample

Have attached the screenshots for your reference. 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Hope some one can throw more light on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Device and logs please?

Comment: Device - iPad Pro 9.7 inch.  The same happens in VLC player in iOS as well.

Comment: Are you resizing / turning the device? If so you need to update the view. And logs please.

Comment: We need sample files demonstrating the issue. So far, this looks like you are not updating the constraints on the video output view correctly. For samples files, please use the anonymous VLC file uploader https://streams.videolan.org/upload/ and give us the file name.

Comment: I have uploaded it and the file name is skate.m4v / skate.mp4